# Why is scanf not working second time in my program?

Tags: c

I am new in c programming . I don't know why this does not work when I'm not changing keyboard input the second time in my program . Why is this not working:   `scanf("%c",&ch3);` what am I missing?
Here is my out put :

[This is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH6Hd.png)

> please enter first the character :
>   A
>   The character is capital letter.
>   please enter second the character :
>   this is invalid character

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int ifelse(char ch);
    int main()
    {

        char ch2=NULL;
        char ch3=NULL;
        printf("please enter first the character : \n");
        scanf("%c",&ch2);

        if(ifelse(ch2)==1) //if(ifelse(ch2)==1)  like this also can be use
            {printf("The character is capital letter.\n");}
             else if (ifelse(ch2)==2){printf("This is small letter character.\n");}
             else if(ifelse(ch2)==3){printf("oh no! numeric letter.\n");}
             else printf("this is invalid character\n");

         printf("please enter second the character : \n");
          scanf("%c",&ch3);
              if(ifelse(ch3)==1) //if(ifelse(ch2)==1)  like this also can be use
            {printf("The character is capital letter.\n");}
             else if (ifelse(ch3)==2){printf("This is small letter character.\n");}
             else if(ifelse(ch3)==3){printf("oh no! numeric letter.\n");}
             else printf("this is invalid character\n");

        return 0;
    }
    int ifelse(char ch){
         if (ch>='A'&&'Z'>=ch){ return 1;}
         else if(ch>='a'&&'z'>=ch){ return 2;}
         else if(ch>='0'&&'9'>=ch){ return 3;}
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `ch3` to see what it contains?

Comment: @John3136 that would require debugging action.  It seems that such skills are banned on the C tag:(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very common problem when using `scanf` to read single characters.

The problem is that `scanf` reads a single character, but leaves the newline in the input buffer, so next time you read a character you read the newline.

The simplest solution is to tell `scanf` to read and ignore leading white-space, by adding a single space in front of the format code, like e.g.

```
scanf(" %c",&ch3);
//     ^
//     |
// Note space here
```

Comment: I am new in c programming .

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most suitable way would be:

```
printf("please enter a character: \n");
scanf("%c",&input_character);
// flushes any previous left character like new line
fflush(stdin);
```

Because if you wrap up this into a function it's clearer that the next scan will succeed without any tricky stuff like "consuming a previous buffered value"